# Why I am getting null value from list which is passed from another Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my project, I am calling themoviedb api and onResponse , i want to share the List to other Activity. When I am passing , I am getting null value from List in other Activity.

Here is my MainActivity.class file :-

```
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    fetchMovieTrailers(5);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
public void fetchMovieTrailers(int id){
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build();

    MovieApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit
             .create(MovieApiInterface.class);

    Call<MovieTrailer> movieTrailerCall = apiInterface
             .getListOfMovieTrailers(id, API_KEY);

    movieTrailerCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieTrailer>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<MovieTrailer> call, Response<MovieTrailer> response) {
             MovieTrailer movieTrailer = response.body();
             List<MovieTrailer.ResultsBean> listOfMovies = movieTrailer.getResults();
             ArrayList<String> trailerKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
             for (int i=0; i<listOfMovies.size(); i++){
                 trailerKeyList.add(listOfMovies.get(i).getKey());
                 Log.d("Trailer Key : ", trailerKeyList.get(i)+"");
             }
              intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Trailer Keys", trailerKeyList);
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<MovieTrailer> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
 }
```

In Second Activity :-

```
ArrayList<String> listOfTrailers = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Trailers Key");
Log.d("Second Activity", listOfTrailers+"");  // I am getting null here
```

Comment: @Zain is right plus you have a typo

"Trailer Keys" -> "Trailer Key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intent data depends on the API response which is not guaranteed, or you can't expect when it occurs, so you need to postpone the `startActivity()` until you get the API response

To do so, move the `startActivity(intent);` to the line after `intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Trailer Keys", trailerKeyList);`

**So your code will be:**

```
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    fetchMovieTrailers(5);

}
public void fetchMovieTrailers(int id){
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .build();

    MovieApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit
             .create(MovieApiInterface.class);

    Call<MovieTrailer> movieTrailerCall = apiInterface
             .getListOfMovieTrailers(id, API_KEY);

    movieTrailerCall.enqueue(new Callback<MovieTrailer>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Call<MovieTrailer> call, Response<MovieTrailer> response) {
             MovieTrailer movieTrailer = response.body();
             List<MovieTrailer.ResultsBean> listOfMovies = movieTrailer.getResults();
             ArrayList<String> trailerKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
             for (int i=0; i<listOfMovies.size(); i++){
                 trailerKeyList.add(listOfMovies.get(i).getKey());
                 Log.d("Trailer Key : ", trailerKeyList.get(i)+"");
             }
              intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Trailer Keys", trailerKeyList);
              startActivity(intent);
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<MovieTrailer> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
           }
       });
 }
```

Comment: you're welcome @ShibuPrasad hope this answers your question; if you feel so, please consider upvote button (▲) to the left of it, and click the checkmark (✓) to accept it.